# find the largest of the three angle of the triangles?

Tags: geometry

> The sides of a triangle are given to be $$ x^2 +x +1 ,$$  $$2x+1,$$  $$x^2-1$$Then find the largest of the three angle of the triangles .
>
> Source:ISI entrance exam sample question [2016](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

I tried  by applying `hero's` formula and then equating to the formula

$$ 0.5 bc  \sin\theta  $$.
But using these methods , then i have to try 3 times for each angle .
And still i cant get the value of x.
I think i can do it throuh by randomly assigning a value to x and then get the value of the angle opposite to the longest side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Note that :

$
\begin{cases}
 x^2+x+1 > 2x+1 > x^2-1, & \text{if } x\in(1,1+\sqrt 3) \\
 x^2+x+1 > x^2-1 > 2x+1, & \text{if } x\in(1+\sqrt 3,+\infty)
\end{cases}$

Hence , the largest angle of the triangle is angle opposite to the side $x^2+x+1$ . Let us denote that angle as $\alpha$ , then according to [Cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) we can write following equality :

$(x^2+x+1)^2=(2x+1)^2+(x^2-1)^2-2(2x+1)(x^2-1)\cdot \cos \alpha $

Comment: And $x^2-1>0$ implies $x>1$ or $x<-1$, while $2x+1>0$ implies $x>-\frac{1}{2}$, hence $x>1$.

Comment: Or being a triangle means that $x^2+x+1>(x^2-1)+(2x+1)$ which simplifies to $1>x$. So there is no triangle.

Comment: @MarkBennet Actually being triangle means that $(x^2-1)+(2x+1) > x^2+x+1$

Comment: @Pedja: Crass error-thanks - it's early in the morning. However the cosine formula seems to reduce to $cos (\alpha)=-\frac12$, though that may be subject to the same source of error.